# OneSignal.init has not been called. Moving subscription action to a waiting task queue

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

Am using onesignal for push notification

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.10.9, 3.99.99]'
```

Getting error message below like this in logcat

```
 E/OneSignal: OneSignal.init has not been called. Moving subscription action to a waiting task queue.
```

I don't no what does it mean.

**Note: my device successfully registered in onesignal and receiving notification too.**

but still am getting error message

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try to use this dependency hope it will help you

 implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6'

 Add the below code snippet if didn't either in application class 
 or inside main activity

 // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .setNotificationReceivedHandler(OneSignalNotificationReceiver(this))
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler(OneSignalNotificationOpened(this))
        .init()
```

Comment: please read my full question without init, how my device is registered with onesignal?